# How do I find time it took to fetch data from Kafka in Spark Structured Streaming job?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, spark-structured-streaming

I want to log how much time it took to fetch data from streaming source (Kafka, in my case) and `getBatch` is one metric logged by `MicrobatchExecution` class which tells time it took to fetch data from streaming source.

I am reading data from Kafka and inside `foreachBatch` loop, I am just printing the count of micro batch. What I observe here is that for all micro batches, `getBatch` is either 0 or 1, whereas addBatch is in thousands (11516, 9244, 8626 ms etc)

Looks like getBatch is always 0 or 1 ms as it not capturing correct time due to lazy evaluation in Spark.

Comment: You can capture more details in - onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent) listener.

Comment: I am taking `getBatch` from that listener object itself but issue is that it is not reflecting the actual time to read from Kafka